# Using "dumb" fan control switch as a remote

Tags: ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch, smart-switch, relay

I have a standard 3-speed fan and dimmable light bulb that I would like to control independently using this specific "dumb" switch, with two independent dimmers for the fan speed and light intensity.

[image: fan control "dumb" switch]

The switch takes a 120V line input and outputs two load outputs, and therefore requires two separate load wires, for the fan and for the light. However, my switch box only provides a single load wire, which I happen to also want to use for a different purpose.

Without having to run new cable to add more wires between the switch and the fan, which setup would allow me to control the fan/light combo using this dumb fan control switch?

Some ideas I have considered:

- treating the switch as two independent dimmers, install two remote AC dimmer pairs, each consisting of a transmitter and receiver, to relay the voltage from the dumb switch to a module connected to the fan/light combo. Does something like this this exist, to remotely relay dimmer voltage from one location to another? I imagine a transmitter with 4 inputs: a line, a neutral and two loads coming from the "dumb" switch, and on the other side a line, neutral and two loads connected to the ceiling fan/light combo. I've searched the Internet for things like "AC dimmer relay" but haven't found anything that meets the requirements so far. Ideally the pair would work without being connected to the Internet or a hub.
- somehow wiring the "dumb" switch to a universal fan/light remote inside the switch box. This would require fitting the remote control inside the switch box as well as translating the two AC dimmer signals into the remote somehow, which seems complicated or not feasible.
- running new cable with more wires. This is a lot of work probably including opening the walls considering the switch location, and I would like to avoid this

Comment: Running a cable might not need to open up walls depending on if the switch is on an inside wall or an outside wall(insulation in the way).  Two switches usually require a /3 cable unless you go with smart switches(and their problems).  If an inside wall and access to the attic, a new cable should be easy.

Comment: A motor speed controller is NOT a dimmer...magic smoke may leave some part or parts of the system if you try to swap one with the other.

Comment: The problem with this inside wall is that it doesn't go all the way up to the attic, so the cable does make some turns so it is hard to move the existing cable. It's also probably hard to add a new cable due to fire-blocks, but probably not hard if I'm willing to open walls.

Answer (score 1):

There are remote controls available for the fan that control the fan speed as well as the light and have dimming capacity.

Some are hand held such as this [fan remote](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Harbor-Breeze-3-Speed-Off-white-Handheld-Universal-Ceiling-Fan-Remote-Control/1000061713?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-dcr-_-ggl-_-LIA_DCR_227_Ceiling-Fans-_-1000061713-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA0PuuBhBsEiwAS7fsNUtM3pA5JtVVuAA_73_thDHaI-g0KVvl0zDHWpDSQwVnAv1tWcBFmBoCwkUQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and there are some controls that can be mounted into the wall box. ( you will have to shop for those yourself, but they are readily available.)

To install any of these you will have to install a receiver ( included with the remote) in the canopy of the fan. You will also have to have constant power to the fan.  That means you need to tie the hot lead in the switch box to the load wire of the fan.

You mentioned that you wanted to use the load for another purpose, but it goes to the fan, so you are limited there. There is no magic to make the fan run with no power lead.

Comment: There are 3 boxes, the ceiling fan and the wall switch boxes meet at a third ceiling light box. The switch box has a single 14/3 cable, the red wire is used to control the kitchen light while the white wire is used for the fan. If I'm able to control the fan via a battery-powered in-wall remote then I'm able to use the white wire as neutral and install a GFCI receptacle.

Comment: The fan does have power and this is not the problem, I have installed another remote into a fan canopy before. The problem I'm trying to solve is that I don't like the complexity of the smart switches, I want two simple and intuitive sliders to turn the fan/lights up or down, instead of buttons that need to pressed multiple times.

Comment: what you want and what you can have are not always alike.

Comment: I also want the remote to fit inside a wall switch and look like a wired wall switch.

The two best options I've found at a local HD store are this battery-powered switch: 
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-3-Speed-Universal-Ceiling-Fan-Wireless-Wall-Control-Damp-Rated-98139/313485917
It has too many buttons and looks too complicated for my taste.

While this one:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hunter-Universal-Damp-Rated-Ceiling-Fan-Wall-Remote-Control-White-99393/313862621
Looks slightly better still requires one load wire to the fan.

Comment: not sure how your comment is relevant to this question.

Comment: My comment is exactly pertinent. Proof is your statement "...too complicated for my TASTE.".   There are solutions to your issues, however you choose to reject them because of your "taste".